# How can i return the else statement in function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

It gives Unexpected token else

```
var sleepCheck = function (numHours) {
  if (sleepCheck >= 8);
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
  else (sleepCheck < 8); 
    return "Get some more shut eye!";
};

sleepCheck(10);
sleepCheck(5);
sleepCheck(8);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statements are checking if `sleepCheck` is greater than or less than something. `sleepCheck` is the name of your function. Replace `sleepCheck` with `numHours` in your `if` statements.

`var sleepCheck = function(numHours) {...}` is equivalent to `function sleepCheck(numHours) {...}`

---

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours) {
  if (numHours >= 8) {
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!"
  }
  // Here you can replace 'else if (numHours < 8)' with 'else'
  else if (numHours < 8) {
    return "Get some more shut eye!"
  }
};

// This will log the output to the console
console.log(sleepCheck(10));
console.log(sleepCheck(5));
console.log(sleepCheck(8));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your semicolons, there are to much. And, there is no else(), you need elseif.

```
var sleepCheck = function (numHours) {
  if (sleepCheck >= 8)
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
  else if (sleepCheck < 8)
    return "Get some more shut eye!";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
var sleepCheck = function (numHours) {
  if (sleepCheck >= 8)
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
  else
    return "Get some more shut eye!";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            function (numHours) {     
                if (numHours >= 8){
                    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";     
                } else { 
                    return "Get some more shut eye!"; 
                }
            };
```

Remove the semicolons at the if and else statements and since you only have two statements you can leave out the qualifiers for the else statement

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use brackets, and some IDE that highlight syntaxis.
You got a recursion in your function.
Here is correct code:

```
var sleepCheck = function (numHours) {
    if (numHours >= 8) {
        return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
    }
    else if (numHours < 8) {
        return "Get some more shut eye!";
    }
};
```